# Initialize a variable inside a template a specified number of times for xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a requirement wherein I need to create records based on xml. I am using xslt to do so. I am using the xml and xslt as provided below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestFile xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="TestFile.xsd">
<AccountEntity AccountNumber = "55904" >
   <TransactionEntity TransactionId = "2337" >
   </TransactionEntity>
   <TransactionEntity TransactionId = "2338" >
   </TransactionEntity>
</AccountEntity>
```

To process the above xml I am using xslt as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:template match="/" >
    <xsl:apply-templates select="AccountEntity" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="AccountEntity">
     <CardNumber>
          <xsl:value-of select="@AccountNumber"/>        
      </CardNumber>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="TransactionEntity" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="TransactionEntity">
      <UniqueId>
        <xsl:value-of select="@TransactionId"/>        
      </UniqueId>
</xsl:template>
```

According to my requirement, I need to be able to create 2 records each having values:
CardNumber: 55904 UniqueId: 2337
CardNumber: 55904 UniqueId: 2338
However, when I am using the above xslt to parse my xml, I am not able to generate 2 records. Can anyone please suggest me a solution so that I am able to create a accountId each time a transactionEntity is present inside the AccountEntity. the number of TransactionEntity inside AccountEntity is not necessarily 2 each time, it can vary from 0 to n number of times.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way, perhaps:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/TestFile">
    <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="AccountEntity/TransactionEntity">
            <Record>
                <CardNumber>
                    <xsl:value-of select="../@AccountNumber"/>        
                </CardNumber>
                <UniqueId>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@TransactionId"/>        
                </UniqueId>
            </Record>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```